# How can i keep my search result when i click next page?

Tags: php

I have a problem with my search system with pagination, my search system have limit the result to 10, so if my search result is 13 result then in the first page it will give me 10 result but when I click the second page my url will become search.php?page=2 and the other 3 result will gone but if i click again the search button the other 3 search result will come out.

This is my search.php:

```
    <div class ="search-left-container">
        <div class ="search-bar-container">
            <form class ="search-form" method="POST"  id="search-form">
                <div class ="search-bar">
                    <input type ="text" name="search" id="search" class ="form-control" placeholder ="search...">
                </div><div class ="search-btn">
                    <input type ="submit" name="submit" id="searchButton" class ="form-control content-btn glyphicon-search" value ="go">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class ="search-content-container" id="search-container">
            <table class="table table-hover" id="resultTable">
                <?php
                if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
                    $page = $_GET['page'];
                    if($page == "" or $page == "1") {
                        $page1 = 0;
                    } else {
                        $page1 = ($page*10)-10;
                    }
                } else {
                    $page1 = 0;
                }
                if($filter == "post" && $time == "all" && $status == "all") {
                        $result2 = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM post WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT $page1, 10") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
                        $count2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

                        if($count2>0) {
                            while($row2= mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){ 
                                $postID = $row2['id'];
                                $result3 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM user_post WHERE post_id = '$postID'") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
                                while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
                                    $getUserName = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$row3['user_id']."'")or die(mysqli_error($connection));
                                    while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($getUserName)) { ?>
                <div class ="post-container" id="search-container">
                            <div class ="post-header-container">
                                <div class ="post-header">
                                    <a href ="post.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($row2['id']);?>&user=<?php echo $row3['user_id']; ?>">
                                        <p class ="post-header-font"><?php echo ($row2['title']); ?></p>
                                    </a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class ="post-user">
                                    <p class ="faded-font">by : <a href="user.php?user=<?php echo $row3['user_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row4['username']; ?></a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class ="post-content-container">
                                <p class ="post-content-font">
                                    <?php echo ($row2['summary']); ?>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class ="post-info-container">
                                <div class ="post-info">
                                    <span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"> views: <?php echo ($row2['views']);?></span>
                                </div><div class ="post-info">
                                    <span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> answers:</span>
                                </div><div class ="post-info">
                                    <span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> status: <?php echo ($row2['status']);?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><?php
                                    }
                                }
                            }?>
                            <div class ="pagination">
                        <?php
                            $result2 = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM post WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
                            $postNum=  mysqli_num_rows($result2);

                            $a=ceil($postNum/10);

                            if(isset($page)){
                                for($i = max(1, $page - 5); $i <= min($page + 5, $a); $i++){
                                    ?><div class ="pagination-selection"><a href="search.php?page=<?php echo ($i); ?>"><?php echo ($i);?></a></div><?php
                                }
                            }else{
                                for($i = max(1, 1 - 5); $i <= min(1 + 5, $a); $i++){
                                    ?><div class ="pagination-selection"><a href="search.php?page=<?php echo ($i); ?>"><?php echo ($i);?></a></div><?php
                                }
                            }

                        ?>
                    </div><?php
                        }
                    }?>
            </table>
        </div><div class ="search-right-container">
        <div class ="search-filter-container">
            <div class ="search-filter-header featured-header">
                <label class ="featured-font">filter by:</label>
            </div>
            <div class ="search-filter-content">
                <form class ="search-form" method="POST">
                    <label class ="radio filter-font">
                        <input type ="radio" name ="filter" value ="post" form="search-form" <?php if(isset($filter) && $filter == 'post')  echo 'checked = "checked"'; ?>>post
                    </label>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class ="search-time-container">
            <div class ="search-time-header featured-header">
                <label class ="featured-font">time</label>
            </div>
            <div class ="search-time-content">
                <form class ="search-form">
                    <label class ="radio filter-font">
                        <input type ="radio" name ="time" value ="all" form="search-form" checked ="checked">all
                    </label>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class ="search-status-container">
            <div class ="search-status-header featured-header">
                <label class ="featured-font">status</label>
            </div>
            <div class ="search-status-content">
                <form class ="search-form">
                    <label class ="radio filter-font">
                        <input type ="radio" name ="status" value ="all" checked ="checked" form="search-form">all
                    </label>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div><?php
            include 'footer.php';
            ?>
```

Comment: try this LIMIT $page1, '.($page1 + 10).'")
 or LIMIT $page1 OFFSET 10

Comment: cannot, it show me got sql error